# Where Is the Beep Sound File Location in Minimalistic Debian?

Tags: linux, audio, debian, terminal, root

I have installed Debian without a desktop environment or the standard system utilities simply because I do not need a desktop environment (yet), and because many of Debian's system utilities are simply not necessary for me (yet—as I say again).

Question: Where can I find the system beep sound file location as I would like to disable it (by renaming the file)? If there is a better solution to disable the system boot sound, I would want to know as the `echo "set bell-style none">> ~/.inputrc` from [Debian's way of disabling beep sounds](https://www.debian.org/doc/manuals/debian-reference/ch09.en.html#_disabling_beep_sounds) does not work. I do **not** want to disable pcspkr (or my computer speaker).

Comment: Are you sure it has a beep file? Reaching back to even the first PC's you can make a beep without a sound file - just "displaying" character 0x7 - https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/523463/why-dev-console-for-remote-beep-echo-command is relevant - but not an answer to your question.

Answer (score 0):

You can check the directory
`/user/share/sounds`

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).